# Different formtastic behavior on two seemingly-identical servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic

I have my app running on production and staging servers.

The identical version of code is running on both, the servers are identical in terms of versions of rails (3.1.3), gems, database schema... I'm at a loss to find any difference.

However, I have a form rendered with formtastic (2.0.0.rc5) which does not render the same on the 2 servers.  In production Formtastic seems to not be correctly taking into account that the view is in the admin module.

The partial in question is at `app/views/admin/composers/_form.html.erb` and the relevant portion of it is:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @composer, :url => @composer.new_record? ? admin_composers_path : admin_composer_path(@composer) do |form| %>
    <%= form.inputs do %>
        <%= form.input :name %>
```

...etc...

On my staging server the form renders as expected as (note the `id` and `name` of the `input` field):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/composers" class="formtastic admin_composer" id="new_admin_composer" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="rotbxUCJeZJuAY6eMRKaQKYdiPN0tlfQSKIeCj6VBUE=" />
  </div>
  <fieldset class="inputs">
    <ol>
      <li class="string input required stringish" id="admin_composer_name_input">
        <label class=" label" for="admin_composer_name">Name<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
        <input id="admin_composer_name" maxlength="255" name="admin_composer[name]" type="text" />
```

...etc...

on the production server, however (note the incorrect `id` and `name`):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/composers" class="formtastic composer" id="new_composer" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="qt++LTRdS+V28dvTRHA7h0vGhSKSoINP8cTjLRCk088=" />
  </div>
  <fieldset class="inputs"><ol>
    <li class="string input required stringish" id="composer_name_input">
      <label class=" label" for="composer_name">Name<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
      <input id="composer_name" maxlength="255" name="composer[name]" type="text" />
```

...etc...

I've been worried that maybe there was something cached somewhere, but as far as I can tell I've forced everything to redeploy in production.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you take the stack on the production server and place it in development mode does it still have the problem?

Comment: You mean starting the app on the production server but specifying staging mode?  Good suggestion, I'll try that.  FWIW, I've now noticed other slight differences in behavior between the 2 environments, so there must be something different between the two that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be what I *thought* it might be, but I still don't quite understand why it was working in one environment and not the other.

My new method in the `controllers/admin/composers_controller.rb` controller originally looked like:

```
def new
  @composer = Composer.new
end
```

(essentially)  But since I was going the route of putting everything in an admin module, what in fact needed to be was:

```
def new
  @composer = Admin::Composer.new
end
```

(I'm using the easy trick of `class Admin::Composer < Composer` instead of trying to get a namespaced controller to refer to the non-namespaced model.)